# How to obtain the weather in a computer's location by using its latitude and longitude in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple program that would show me the weather in the location of the computer. I took the location by

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.ip('me')
print(g.latlng)
```

But after that I don't know what to do. Can someone tell me what I can do to obtain the desired result?

Comment: Do you want to check it agains a webpage or...? What is the question/purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to visit https://openweathermap.org/api , it offers some free api to get weather data in json format. You need to register to access the api but it's totally free. You can get the current weather and also forecasts with a free subscription; if you need more, you can also pay